# 64 bit version of SQL Server Report Builder

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Is SQL server report builder avaialble in 64bit version?

I have downloaded and installed Sql Server 2012 Report Builder (version 3) from the following url,
http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/confirmation.aspx?id=29072

That report builder executable is 32 bit. Is there any 64bit version available ?

Thanks
Prakash

Comment: Why do you need a 64 bit version?

Comment: I don't need a 64 bit version. I am evaluating to move all the components used in one of the product to 64 bit. I am unable to find that info in anywhere in the internet.

Comment: Generally client tools like report builder come in 32 bit (because they rarely require > 3G memory) and server applications come in 64 bit.

Comment: Because 32-bit SSRS requires 32-bit Oracle drivers installed on the client machine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Report builder 3 only comes in 32bit.